# In Ruby, how can I use OpenSSL::PKCS7's encrypt + decrypt functions?

Tags: ruby, encryption, pkcs#7

Can anyone advise how to encrypt + decrypt a message in Ruby using OpenSSL::PKCS7? (I'm not trying to sign + verify. That much I can do. *I need to write tests for some existing code which calls `OpenSSL::PKCS7#decrypt`.*)

I've pored over what little documentation I can find online, but to no effect. When I call `decrypt`, I get the following on stderr:

`` example.rb:13:in `decrypt': decrypt error (OpenSSL::PKCS7::PKCS7Error) ``

```rb
require 'openssl'

# Create a key & self-signed certificate
key = OpenSSL::PKey::RSA.new 1024
cert = OpenSSL::X509::Certificate.new
cert.public_key = key.public_key
cert.not_before = Time.now
cert.not_after = Time.now + 2**12
cert.sign key, OpenSSL::Digest.new('SHA256')

# Encrypt & decrypt
ciphertext = OpenSSL::PKCS7.encrypt([cert], "plaintext").to_pem
decrypted = OpenSSL::PKCS7.new(ciphertext).decrypt(key, cert) # => error
```

I've furthermore experimented with specifying a cipher and flags for the `OpenSSL::PKCS7::encrypt` call, but to no effect.

*I'm using Ruby 2.6.9.*

Comment: On Ruby 3.2.1 with OpenSSL 3.1.0 on both macOS and Alpine 3.17.2 the line `ciphertext = OpenSSL::PKCS7.encrypt([cert], 'plaintext').to_pem` raises an exception with `encrypt: malloc failure (OpenSSL::PKCS7::PKCS7Error)`. Can you please include your specific versions to help replicate it?

Comment: Thanks, @anothermh. I'm on `Ruby 2.6.9`

Comment: Well, it appears the problem was in the cert. Specifying `cert.serial = 0` gets this code working.